# Laravel5 - Getting error in paginating search results

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a problem with the pagination of search results. I get the first page right, but for page 2 I get this error:

```
QueryException in Connection.php line 729:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'page' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `books` where `id` like %% and `page` like %2% and `books`.`deleted_at` is null)
```

My route:

```
Route::get('books/search', 'BookController@searchForm');
Route::get('books/results', 'BookController@searchProcess');
```

Controller:

```
use Search; //search trait
public function searchForm(){
    return view('books.search.form');
 }
public function searchProcess(Request $request){
     $result = $this->performSearch($request, $this->model);
     return view('books.search.result', compact('result'));
}
```

Search Trait (A class in another file):

```
protected function performSearch($request, $model){
    $searchFields = $request->toArray();
    unset($searchFields['_token']);
    $searchFields = array_filter($searchFields);
    if (empty($searchFields)) {
        return back();
    }
    $list = $model->where('id', 'like', '%%');
    foreach ($searchFields as $column => $value) {
        $list->where($column, 'like', '%'.$value.'%');
    }
    return $list->paginate(10);
}
```

View for showing results:

```
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
            <tr>
                <th>Results</th>
            </tr>
            @foreach($result as $datum)
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="{{route('books.show', $datum->id)}}">{{$datum->title}}</a></td>
                </tr>    
            @endforeach
        </table>
    </div>
    @if($result->lastPage() > 1)
        <nav class="text-center">
            {{$result->links()}}
        </nav>
    @endif
```

I am using Laravel 5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems you are passing page parameter in the query so i think you need to remove page parameter from the query building

```
protected function performSearch($request, $model)
{
    $searchFields = $request->except(['_token', 'page']); // get all fields except _token and page you can add more parameters in array if they are in request but not in database table column
    $searchFields = array_filter($searchFields);
    if (empty($searchFields)) {
        return back();
    }
    $list = $model->where('id', 'like', '%%');
    foreach ($searchFields as $column => $value) {
        $list->where($column, 'like', '%'.$value.'%');
    }
    return $list->paginate(10);
}
```

Comment: did it worked for you? seems that was the only problem about parameters.
if it worked mark the question as correct so others can get reference.

Comment: Thanks for solving a part of the problem. The other problem is that the search tokens are not passed to page2, so no results. If -for example- I am searching for title="php", when I go to page2 it will search for title="". How can I solve this?

Comment: you can pass all the filtered values as parameters in the url so if in page1 title="php" then page link becomes /page2?title=php
and so you can get title="php" in page 2 also in $request->params('page');
use route() or action() method to generate url with parameters.

Comment: How I can pass them in the url? I am using Laravel out-of-the-box pagination.

Comment: you are showing search result inside searchProcess, and returning view so where you else want to pass the filters?

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand. I'm really a newbie. Where should I use the route() method? in the view or in controller? and how?

Comment: @MahfuzulAlam I updated the original post with the view.

Comment: Considering you're using Laravel 4.2 try with `{{$result->appends(Input::except('page', '_token'))->links()}}`

Comment: well, I'm using v5.2. I got the idea, I'll do my research and experiment a little and get back. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @MahfuzulAlam  Returning to the project after months, I fixed the problem with adding {{$result->appends($query)->links()}} in the pagination div inside view files. tx for help.